# Move autofocus after selecting the select option

Tags: javascript, html

Want to ask, how do you move the cursor automatically after selecting the form select option?

```
<select name="id" class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
```

I want after I select select the cursor will automatically go to the text name input form

Comment: where do you want to move the cursor?

Comment: Please be more precise and clear.

Comment: in form text input name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var input = document.querySelector('input');

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
  input.focus();
});
```

```html
<select name="id" class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
```